# Having trouble with compiling error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm a beginner at Java and I'm working on a project for class. I also find Java pretty hard to grasp and I'm having trouble with this compiling error. It's just 1 error which confuses me even more because I dont get one when I use the variable elsewhere.

---

### *** Error ***

File: D:\Programming\Project 2\Product.java  [line: 47]

Error: newCompType cannot be resolved to a variable

```
public class Product
{
  //Instance variables
  private String name; //Name of Product
  private String compType; //Type of Product
  private double price; //Price of Product
  private int quantity; //How many computers

  //Constructors
  public Product()
  {
    name = "Dell";
    compType = "Laptop";
    price = 200;
    quantity = 1;
  }

  public Product(String newName, String newCompType, double newPrice, int newQuantity)
  {
    name = newName;
    compType = newCompType;
    price = newPrice;
    quantity = newQuantity;
  }

  //Instance methods
  public void printData()
  {
    System.out.println("Name of computer: " + name);
    System.out.println("Type of computer: " + compType);
    System.out.println("Number of computers: " + quantity);
    System.out.println("Cost of computer: " + price);
  }

  public void setName(String newName)
  {
    name = newName;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public void setCompType(String setCompType)
  {
    compType = newCompType;
  }

  public String getCompType()
  {
    return compType;
  }

  public void setPrice(double newPrice)
  {
    price = newPrice;
  }

  public double getPrice()
  {
    return price;
  }
  public void setQuantity(int newQuantity)
  {
    quantity = newQuantity;
  }

  public int getQuantity()
  {
    return quantity;
  }

   public String toString(){
   return name + " " + compType + " " + quantity + " " + price + "\n";
 }
}
```

Comment: So read your code at the indicated line, and see if you can't spot the problem. It's pretty clear - almost jumps out and smacks you in the nose.

Answer (score 2):

In :

```
public void setCompType(String setCompType) {
    compType = newCompType; // <-- should be setCompType instead of newCompType
}
```

Comment: They should both be `newCompType`.

Comment: @shmosel you know what I mean :)

Comment: @alfasin Well damn. Now I feel dumb lol.This project will be the end of me x_x Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Xiraiya see shmosel's comment. The variable name should not be `setCompType` - the name `newCompType` is better!